# offsets when looking objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have something like this in the controller:

```
@puzzleGames = Game.where("category = 'puzzle'").limit(8)
```

but in the view I display them in 2 seperate areas, 4 in one and 4 in the other.

Instead of doing something like this:

```
<% @puzzleGames.each do |puzzleGame| %>
```

to loop through all elements, is it possible to loop to and from a finite number (0-3,4-7)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try with this

```
@gameSlices = @puzzleGames.each_slice(4)
```

Then use `@gameSlices.first` and `@gameSlices.last`

**EDIT:** Just turned out that `@gameSlices.next` can be very useful in this case. It will return each slice one by one.

or you can use a block like

```
@puzzleGames.each_slice(4) do |slice|
    # Do your stuffs with slice
end
```

Comment: @puzzleGames.each_slice(4) do |slice| will get slice 0-3 or does it create two subsets (of size 4) from @puzzleGames?

Comment: It will create two slices like `[0..3]` and `[4..7]` and will fire the block **two** times. That means on first iteration the slice will contain **first half** and in next iteration it will contain **second half**.

Comment: Here is a link I just played with http://ideone.com/fm0pT. You can see the output of the iteration there.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`@puzzleGames[0...4]` and `@puzzleGames[4...8]`

Answer (score 0):

```
@puzzleGames = Game.where("category = 'puzzle'").limit(8)
@firstFourPuzzleGames = arr.each_slice(4).map(&:first)
@lastFourPuzzleGames = arr.each_slice(4).map(&:last)
```

and the

```
<% @firstFourPuzzleGames.each do |puzzleGame| %>
<% end %>
```

and

```
<% @lastFourPuzzleGames.each do |puzzleGame| %>
<% end %>
```